# How can I determine if a function wrapped in an if statement gets called?

Tags: c#, moq

I have a class, like this one:

```
public class SomeClass: ISomeClass
{
     public async Task<ServiceResponse> PerformAction(Context context)
     {
          if(IsPartner(context))
          {
               SendTextMessageAsync(context);
          }
     }

     public bool IsPartner(Context context)
     {
          return SomeStaticHelperClass.GetIsPartner(context.PartnerId);
     }

     public async void SendTextMessageAsync(Context context)
     {
          // sends the message
     }
}
```

`ISomeClass` exposes all three methods.

I'm using Moq and I would like to write a test that verifies

- when `IsPartner` returns true
- then `SendTextMessage` is called once.

I've tried everything I can think of.

This is my latest attempt:

```cs
public class ReceiptServiceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async void SendReceiptsProofsNeededNudgeAsync_ShouldCallSendTextMessageAsync_WhenSessionPartnerIdIsNotNullOrEmptyString()
    {
        var context = new Context { PartnerId = "12345" };
        var mockSomeClass = new Mock<ISomeClass>();

        // force IsPartner to return true
        mockSomeClass.Setup(m => m.IsPartner(context)).Returns(true);

        // call PerformAction which should call SendTextMessageAsync
        // because IsPartner will return true
        await mockSomeClass.Object.PerformAction(context);

        // verify SendTextMessageAsync was actually called
        mockSomeClass.Verify(m => m.SendTextMessageAsync(It.IsAny<Context>()), Times.AtLeastOnce);
    }
}
```

I keep getting following error:

> (Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: m => m.SendTextMessageAsync)

which i'm guessing is because `SendTextMessageAsync` is never called. I'm stuck here though, I don't understand how to properly call it.

I know some (or a lot) of this code doesn't make sense, I've changed it for brevity.

What I'm really just trying to figure out is how can I determine if a function (SendTextMessageAsync) is called when it is wrapped in an *if statement* that calls another function that returns true.

Comment: If you remove the 'if' is the call picked up correctly? If you step though using the debugger is the line hit?

Comment: No, I still get same error.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Your mock is a mock of an interface which has no implementation. Generally when verifying invocations, your SUT will take a dependency, then you verify that that dependency was called. You don't generally verify that a method within the SUT itself was called.

Comment: @johnsontroye Please try to avoid to use `async void`. Please use `async Task` even for unit tesitng.

Answer (score 1):

As rgvlee as already pointed out you can only mock dependencies and verify their method calls.

In your case `SomeStaticHelperClass` is your dependency and its `GetIsPartner` method that could be verified.

Unfortunately static classes are not good candidates for mocking. If you could replace that static class reference to an interface then you would be able to mock that easily.

#### `SomeClass` uses `IPartnerService`

```cs
public class SomeClass: ISomeClass
{
     private readonly IPartnerService partnerSvc;
     public SomeClass(IPartnerService partnerSvc)
     {
          this.partnerSvc = partnerSvc;
     }

     public async Task<ServiceResponse> PerformAction(Context context)
     {
          if(IsPartner(context))
          {
               SendTextMessageAsync(context);
          }
     }

     public bool IsPartner(Context context)
     {
          return partnerSvc.GetIsPartner(context.PartnerId);
     }

     public async void SendTextMessageAsync(Context context)
     {
          // sends the message
     }
}
```

#### `SomeClass` is using a `IPartnerService` mock during unit testing

```cs
public class ReceiptServiceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task GivenAPartner_WhenICallPerformAction_ThenItCallsPartnerService()
    {
        //Arrange
        const string partnerId = "12345";
        var context = new Context { PartnerId = partnerId };
        var partnerSvcMock = new Mock<IPartnerService>();
        partnerSvcMock
          .Setup(svc => svc.GetIsPartner(partnerId))
          .Returns(true);

        var SUT = new SomeClass(partnerSvcMock);         

        //Act
        _ = await SUT.PerformAction(context);

        //Assert
        partnerSvcMock.Verify(svc => svc.GetIsPartner(partnerId), Times.Once);
    }
}
```